# Binary Search implementation via java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

Please see the below java source code for binary search implementation

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        int y = binarySearch(x, 11);
        System.out.println(y);

    }

    public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int value) {
        int searchedIndex = -1;
        int first = 0;
        int last = arr.length - 1;
        int mid;

        while (first <= last) {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;

            if (arr[mid] == value) {
                searchedIndex = mid;
                break;
            } else {
                if (value < arr[mid]) {
                    last = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    first = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return searchedIndex;
    }
}
```

**int last = arr.length - 1**  is -1 compulsory or not. I feel that code works fine either **last = arr.length - 1**. If its compulsory please explain why.

Comment: The array starts with 0 and ends with lengh-1. What is the problem?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but searching arrays you have to get the length -1 because the array indexes start at 0. So if there are 5 elements in an array, you get them by `array[0]`, `array[1]` etc up to `array[4]`. So if you try access `array.length`, it will try get `array[5]` which doesn't exist and will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: It affect to mid calculation when there is -1.Iam not asking about array size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-1` is needed for one very specific case: when you search for a value that is larger than the largest value in the array. For example, calling your function with

```
int y = binarySearch(x, 50);
```

will throw an ArrayOutOfBounds exception. That's because `mid` will eventually be equal to `last`, and without the `-1`, `last` is past the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much .Good explanation

Comment: @NipunTharuksha You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

[**Arrays**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) already have a method [**binarySearch**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)) you can just use :

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
int r = Arrays.binarySearch(x, 11);
```

Comment: Good point, but it is most likely forbidden to be used in an educational task that is given to learn basics.

Comment: I need to implement by myself rather than using java libraries.So please explain is -1 compulsory

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I tried your code and it return 10 same as my answer, please [check the demo online](https://ideone.com/cMMMLi)

Comment: @deHaar I agree but the OP doesn't mention that, for that my answer was like this, also the OP can inspire from the source code of that method :)

Comment: @YCF_L  this algorithm works either -1 included or not what I want to know is that is it compulsory